# Is it possible to combine differents software architectures?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, architecture, onion-architecture

I have been developing a Web Rest API with ASP.NET Core and I have seen in a course the combination of two software architectures (Onion and MVC) and it was very confusing, so I was wondering if that is possible. ?

And I would like to know if it is possible to combine different architectures with Microservices Architecture.

Comment: Why do you think that these two architectures can't be combined? As a good [starting point](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/onion-architecture-in-asp-net-core-mvc/)

Comment: Is this question specific to your Web Rest API or is it a more general informational question. If the first, it would be helpful to learn more about your project's current architecture.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your confusion has it root in seeing MVC as an architecture for the complete solution. Instead it is a pattern that is used *only* in the UI. The target of the onion architecture is exactly this: Limiting the impact of a decision like "I use MVC for the UI." only to the UI. So this is no contradiction. :-)

Yes, within an onion architecture you can use the MVC pattern in the UI.

Yes, within a micro service you can use onion architecture. You should have a closed onion architecture for a micro service. You should not build your onion architecture by using micro services. (Then you may have misunderstood micro services.)